# python dictionary iteration not working as expected

Tags: python, json, dictionary

i am trying to modify json file with transcript data in order to combine each conversation segments in a sentence.

This is a link to my input data:
https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.34cfd15f2c1f461f9e7a7ab57431de79

output data:
https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.99a89b483ae84c7f8913da5ecfd3f4a3

My goal is to get each item in the input array combine all conversation items , check if the next item is from new speaker. If yes, i reset the string else i add the new items either until speaker changes or until the string grows to 500 characters. For some reason as you see in the output my data is constantly repeated.

this is my code:

```
import json



with open('input-data.json', 'r') as f:
    text = json.load(f)
    
segment_string = ''
current_speaker = ''
sentimentData_full = {}
sentimentData_final = []
for item in text: 
    conversation_segment_list = item['conversation_items']
    speaker = item['speaker_label']
    for segment in conversation_segment_list:
        if len(segment_string) >= 500 or speaker != current_speaker:     
            segment_string = ''
            segment_string += f"{segment['content']} "
            current_speaker = speaker
        else:
            segment_string += f"{segment['content']} "
            continue
    sentimentData = {}
    sentimentData_full['speaker_label'] = speaker
    sentimentData_full['segment_string'] = segment_string                
    sentimentData_final.append(sentimentData_full.copy())
    sentimentData_full = {}       

app_json = json.dumps(sentimentData_final)
with open('output-data.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(app_json)
```

i have been working for many hours on this and any help would be appreciated.
also here is an example of what is wrong now(just in case my explanation is not clear enough):

current, incorrect output:

```
[
  {
    "speaker_label": "spk_0",
    "segment_string": "mhm . "
  },
  {
    "speaker_label": "spk_0",
    "segment_string": "mhm . You have reached a as in so far . This is Donna . I'll be assisting you with your inquiries today . Please be informed that this call is being recorded and monitored for quality assurance purposes . How may I help you ? "
  },
  {
    "speaker_label": "spk_1",
    "segment_string": "Um , well , I bought . All right , I got this , um , essence of argon oil , um , "
  },
  {
    "speaker_label": "spk_1",
    "segment_string": "Um , well , I bought . All right , I got this , um , essence of argon oil , um , for shipping , handling and handling costs . 599 a sample of it . "
  },
  {
    "speaker_label": "spk_1",
    "segment_string": "Um , well , I bought . All right , I got this , um , essence of argon oil , um , for shipping , handling and handling costs . 599 a sample of it . And , um , if I want to cancel the order , I had to do it within , "
  } 
]
```

expected output:

```
{
    "speaker_label": "spk_0",
    "segment_string": "mhm . You have reached a as in so far . This is Donna . I'll be assisting you with your inquiries today . Please be informed that this call is being recorded and monitored for quality assurance purposes . How may I help you ? "
  },
  {
    "speaker_label": "spk_1",
    "segment_string": "Um , well , I bought . All right , I got this , um , essence of argon oil , um , for shipping , handling and handling costs . 599 a sample of it . And , um , if I want to cancel the order , I had to do it within , "
  } 
]
```

Comment: Your input data link does not show anything.

Comment: should be ok now.thanks

Comment: Is all of the code after `text = json.load(f)` meant to be indented that far or is that just an issue from copying to SO?

Comment: well you are right, they should not be. I fixed it now. The output is however exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to debug what was wrong in yours but I created one from scratch. The keys can be adjusted according to your requirement but for now, I've used speakers as keys.

```
import json
import re
from collections import defaultdict

speakers = defaultdict(list)

with open("try.json", "r") as f:
    text = json.load(f)

for item in text:
    conversation_segment_list = item["conversation_items"]
    speaker = item["speaker_label"]
    for segment in conversation_segment_list:
        speakers[speaker].append(segment["content"])

speakers = {
    speaker: re.sub(r"[\s]([.,?])", r"\1", " ".join(words))[:500]
    for speaker, words in speakers.items()
}

print(speakers)
```

### Output:

```
{
    "spk_0": "mhm. You have reached a as in so far. This is Donna. I'll be assisting you with your inquiries today. Please be informed that this call is being recorded and monitored for quality assurance purposes. How may I help you? Okay, I didn't have I'm happy to assist you. Um, for me to be able to pull up your, uh, subscription here, could you kind of provide me your first and your last name? Oh, l y and then Yes, l a k e. Yes. Okay. Just, uh, go ahead to pull up here. A subscription here or your account",
    "spk_1": "Um, well, I bought. All right, I got this, um, essence of argon oil, um, for shipping, handling and handling costs. 599 a sample of it. And, um, if I want to cancel the order, I had to do it within, uh, 15 days. And so that is, um when I want I wanted to do, I didn't want to. I didn't want to get, you know, like a monthly for what is it at $3 a month? Okay, I can't afford that. I'm Carolyn. C a R O L Y N lake l a k e It's, uh, Lake 3921 at hotmail dot com. Uh, 3 10 Warren Avenue number 2 July Wy",
}
```